# JavaScript if statement doesn't work

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have this simple if statement that compare two object properties (string):

```
if(client.room == sender.room){ /*Doesn't work*/ }
```

I was surprised that they doesn't pass so I debug:

```
console.log(client.room + " == " + sender.room);
```

And the output was correct:

```
#General == #General
```

So I tried many things but still doesn't work...

Then I tried this:

```
var clientRoom = client.room;
if(clientRoom == '#General'){ /*Work!*/ }

if(client.room == '#General'){ /*Work!*/ }
```

But I'm still stuck... How can I compare these two object property to see if they're equal?

Comment: What is `client.room`? What is `sender.room`? If they're strings, `==` absolutely will work. If they're objects that have a `toString` method, `==` won't work for different objects with the same contents.

Comment: The string form of an object doesn't tell us that much about what the object is. It doesn't seem to be a plain string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like `client.room` and `sender.room` are objects with a `toString` method. Two different objects are not `==` to each other, even if they have the same contents and their `toString` matches.

Your `client.room == "#General"` works because `==` will coerce its operands to try to make them the same type. In that case, it coerces `client.room` to a string (via `client.room`'s `toString`).

You need to decide what criteria you want to use to determine whether the objects are equivalent, and use those criteria when comparing them. You might encapsulate that in an `equals` method or similar.

Illustration of the problem:

```js
class Room {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  toString() {
    return "#" + this.name;
  }
}

const room1 = new Room("General");
const room2 = new Room("General");

console.log(room1 == room2);        // false
console.log(room1 + " - " + room2); // #General - #General
console.log(room1 == "#General")    // true
```

Or in ES5 syntax:

```js
function Room(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
Room.prototype.toString = function() {
  return "#" + this.name;
};

var room1 = new Room("General");
var room2 = new Room("General");

console.log(room1 == room2);        // false
console.log(room1 + " - " + room2); // #General - #General
console.log(room1 == "#General")    // true
```

Illustration of adding an `equals` and using that:

```js
class Room {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  toString() {
    return "#" + this.name;
  }
  equals(other) {
    return other && other.name === this.name;
  }
}

const room1 = new Room("General");
const room2 = new Room("General");
const room3 = new Room("SomethingElse");

console.log(room1 == room2);        // false
console.log(room1.equals(room2));   // true
console.log(room1.equals(room3));   // false
```

Or in ES5 syntax:

```js
function Room(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
Room.prototype.toString = function() {
  return "#" + this.name;
};
Room.prototype.equals = function(other) {
  return other && other.name === this.name;
};

var room1 = new Room("General");
var room2 = new Room("General");
var room3 = new Room("SomethingElse");

console.log(room1 == room2);        // false
console.log(room1.equals(room2));   // true
console.log(room1.equals(room3));   // false
```

Comment: Yeah the toString() method solves my problem. Thank you!